# Uploading File via FormData

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am trying to upload a file to a Node backend that uses Multer. Multer requires the form to be submitted a specific way. If it's not submitted that way, the `request.file` parameter will be `undefined`. I have created an approach that works by using brute force. That working approach looks like this:

**index-1.html:**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
  <input type="file" id="selectedFile" name="selectedFile" /><br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
</form>
...
var btn = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];
  var data = new FormData(form);
  console.log(data);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    url: "/upload",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log("SUCCESS!");
    },
    error: function (e) {
      console.log("ERROR : ", e);
    }
  });
});
```

The code above successfully posts the file to my server. That server has the following:

**server.js**

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('selectedFile'), function(req, res) {
  if (req.file) {
    console.log('file uploaded');
  } else {
    console.log('no file');
  }

  res.send({});
});
```

Using the code above, "file uploaded" is displayed in the console window as expected. However, I need a more dynamic approach. For that reason, I need to programmatically build the form in JavaScript. In an attempt to do that, I've created the following:

**index-2.html**
    [my UI]

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var form = document.createElement('form');
  form.action = '/upload';
  form.method = 'POST';
  form.enctype = 'multipart/form-data';

  var node = document.createElement("input");                        
  node.name = 'selectedFile';
  node.value = GLOBAL_SELECTED_FILE;
  form.appendChild(node);

  var data = new FormData(form);
  data.append('id', this.id);
  console.log(data);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/profile-picture/upload',
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',                          
    data: data,                            
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(res) {
      console.log('success!');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      console.log('error');
    }
  });
});
```

This second approach does not work. To clarify, the `GLOBAL_SELECTED_FILE` variable is the data of a file that was selected from an input element. The data is loaded via the FileReader api. That looks like this:

```
var GLOBAL_SELECTED_FILE = null;

var fileReader = new FileReader();      
fileReader.onload = function(e) {
  GLOBAL_SELECTED_FILE = e.target.result;
}
fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileSelected);  // file selected comes from the onchange event on a <input type="file">..</input> element
```

Basically, I'm loading a preview of the image. Anyways, when I hit the submit button in the working version (index-1.html), I notice in Fiddler that a different value is sent over the value sent in index-2.html.

With the approach in index-1.html, Fiddler shows something like this in the "TextView" tab:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary183mBxXxf1HoE4Et
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="selectedFile"; filename="picture.PNG"
Content-Type: image/png

 PNG
```

However, when I look in the "TextView" tab in Fiddler for the data sent via index-2.html, I see the following:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary9UHBP02of1OI5Zb6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="selectedFile"

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg[A LOT MORE TO GO]
```

It's like the FormData is using two different encodings for the same value. Yet, I don't understand why. How do I get index-2.html to send the image in the same format as index-1.html so that Multer will populate the req.file property?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In index-1.html, you are using a file input:

```
<input type="file" id="selectedFile" name="selectedFile" />
```

In index-2.html, you are creating an ordinary form input (not a file input):

```
var node = document.createElement("input");                        
node.name = 'selectedFile';
node.value = GLOBAL_SELECTED_FILE;
form.appendChild(node);
```

To create a file input, you would need to add `node.type = 'file'`. However, you won't be able to set the value because [browser security restrictions prevent setting the value of file inputs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Instead, what you need to do is append the file that was selected by the user to the `FormData` object:

```
var data = new FormData(form);
data.append('id', this.id);
data.append('selectedFile', $('#fileInputElement')[0].files[0]);
```